# iPhone/iPad app development connect to a java http server

Tags: java, ipad, http, web-applications, connection

Ok so I am still new to Objective C and currently learning it. I wanted to make an app where people can login and submit data to a database. I have research and found that I need to connect to a web server (I will use a Java web server) and from this server, it will communicate to the database server.

**However, I am just wondering exactly how I would connect from an IPad app (that I will make in the future) to a Java App Server such as Glashfish**. To do this, what kind of web app would I make (servlets?)? If I did, would I use the URL wrting method to transfer data?

I would want to use a http connection since I am using Glassfish.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose Restful API through the java web application; and access these api in your iOS app. There are many rest-client library for iOS now.

You can also write data to url connection directly, but it's tedious and complex.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like the idea of URL writing for this situation